# How to display data as HTML for each item in database efficiently?

Tags: php

I have a database called products. In this DB I have a field called image_id. I would like to display each image_id in a cell of a table, with a max of 3 cells per row.

This is what I have written. I just want to make sure that I am not stressing out my server for no reason...

```
$HTML="<table><tr>";

$i=0;
$count=0;
@mysql_select_db($DB_DATABASE);
$query="SELECT image_id FROM produts";
$res=mysql_query($query); 
while(list($image_id)=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
  {  
   $count++;
   $i++; 

$HTML.="<td>$image_id</td>";  
      if(($i%3)==0) 
         $HTML.="</tr><tr>"; 
  }

$HTML.="</table>";
```

My understanding is that this should output something like this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>image_id_1</td>
        <td>image_id_2</td>
        <td>image_id_3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>image_id_4</td>
        <td>image_id_5</td>
        <td>image_id_6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is my coding format acceptable or can this be done more efficiently? Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sevenseacat I never knew that site even existed! awesome, thanks for the link man, i've been wanting to have my code reviewed for a while now but didnt know if SO was the right place.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will use that section you linked going forward.

Comment: @pavan an d that makes your and mine comment of topic :)

Comment: Donnot ignore the error/warning by `@` until you really know how and where exactly to use it ...nd you are using deprecated mysql_* function (in newer php version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats exactly how one would go about it. It's the way I've done it. thats the great thing about php, you can insert html code in loops to create a dynamic html page based on the content coming in from your database.

This is why php and html go well together, you can form great dynamic pages.

You're on the right track mate. Someone may suggest a more elegant solution that does not mean your solution is false or inefficient. It's even there in the w3Schools tutorial website in the php and mysql section. So you're fine.

Goodluck!

**UPDATE 1**

One improvement you could do is doing some if checking and return something else if there is no data to show from the database otherwise your webpage will just show a blank page since the while loop wouldnt be executed when there is not data coming from your database.

Comment: Imho w3school isnt a good resource to read , though whatever float the boat.....

Comment: @NullPoiиteяღ Sorry, I didn't know. I'm an iOS developer, and coded in PHP a VERY long time in my school years. aha it was the only resource I could think of relating to this post! Hey, leave w3school alone! It was my go to point whenever I'd forget how to connect to a database with PHP and MySQL. :p